# Fetching chart data in a loop and assigning to chart in Angular 2

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular2-template, ng2-charts

I'm using [ng2-charts](http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) component in my Angular 2 web application to display charts. The ready made samples gave me a fair idea of displaying the chart on my web page using Angular and TypeScript

**Angular tags in my HTML web page**

```
<base-chart class="chart"
                [data]="doughnutChartData"
                [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
                [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
                (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
                (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></base-chart>
```

**Typescript**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgClass} from '@angular/common';

import {CHART_DIRECTIVES} from '../../../ng2-charts';

// webpack html imports
let template = require('./doughnut-chart-demo.html');

@Component({
  selector: 'doughnut-chart-demo',
  template: template,
  directives: [CHART_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class DoughnutChartDemoComponent {
  // Doughnut
  public doughnutChartLabels:string[] = ['Download Sales', 'In-Store Sales', 'Mail-Order Sales'];
  public doughnutChartData:number[] = [350, 450, 100];
  public doughnutChartType:string = 'doughnut';

  // events
  public chartClicked(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }

  public chartHovered(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

However, in case of multiple data widgets with each widget having a chart component. How should I bind the data to the chart?

I loop through a list of **siteData** object looking for **status** property.
Assigning this property to the chart data.

```
<template ngFor #item [ngForOf]="siteData" #i="index">
    <div class="box-body box-profile">
                <h1 class="profile-username text-center" style="text-align: left;font-size: 25px;font-weight: 500;">{{item.siteName}}</h1>
                <hr style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans Serif;background: #E8EAEB;min-height: 100%;width: 100%;font-size: 0.9vw;"/>
                <h1 class="profile-username text-center" style="text-align: left;">Summary</h1>
                <ul class="products-list product-list-in-box">
                    <li class="item">
                        <base-chart class="chart"
                                    [data]="item.status"
                                    [chartType]="siteChartType"
                                    (chartHover)="siteChartHovered($event)"
                                    (chartClick)="siteChartClicked($event)">
                        </base-chart>
                    </li>
                    </ul>

            </div>
</template>
```

However, this doesn't work. It is accepting the data as string.!!!

i.e. for ex: if the status (datatype number) is 85, in the line

```
[data]="item.status"
```

then the chart accepts this as '8' and '5' respectively.

However, if I verify this with a simple  tag, Something like this using the

moustache (double curl braces)

```
<h1 class="headline text-green">{{item.status}}</h1>
```

I do the get the data what I need. i.e **85**  gets printed

Not sure where I'm going wrong in assigning the data to the chart.

Any guidance in the right direction is much appreciated

Comment: What does "this doesn't work" and "It is accepting the data as string" mean"

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: Hi I have edited my post

Comment: Just saw. Thanks, this makes it clear, but I have no idea.

Comment: But funny thing is I get the data If i use {{ }} operator.

Comment: `{{}}` converts it to a string before passing. Maybe the component has issues accepting a value of type number.

Comment: Yeah. That is what adding to the confusion :)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: I got it working by referring your response for another post. Had to use `[data]="[item.status]"` 
Danke schone :) Please post your response so that I can accept this as an answer

Comment: You could add this as an answer and then accept it after a while to indicate this problem is solved.